# How to do contingency table analysis with tidy data in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets assume I have the following data.

```
Table  is_exposed  disease   value
1           1        1         4
1           1        0         100
1           0        1         20
1           0        0         80
2           1        1         10
2           1        0         40
2           0        1         15
2           0        0         30
```

`Table` represents each of the 2x2 tables which have the following form.

```
                   Exposed    Not Exposed        
                 ---------- --------------
Disease             a          b
No Disease          c          d
```

How would I do the following calculations in dplyr?

1. Risk `a/(a+b)` and `c/(c+d)` [Should be 4 values with the above data]
2. Risk Difference `risk2-risk1` [Should be 2 values with the above data]
3. Odds ratio `ad/bc` [Should be 2 values with the above data]

## Output format

```
Table  disease    risk
1         1       .167
1         0       .556
2         1       .2
2         0       .33
```

and

```
Table risk_diff odds_ratio
1        .389       .16
2        .13        .5
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the output format you'd like.

Comment: Shouldn't you only get 1 risk per table if it is `a/(a+d)`? For example, Table 1 has Risk = 4/(4+80). Where do you get the second Risk for Table 1?

Comment: @useR Risk is by row or by column, depending on what you want to know the risk of. I think you can think of risk as the proportion of a value over its marginal.

Comment: I just saw my typo. `a/(a+b)` is what it should be.

Comment: According to your table, `a` is when both `disease` _and_ `exposed` are true, so by your formula `a/(a+b)`, you won't get a risk for when `disease=0`, since that should then be `c/(c+d)`. Please update your question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  split(df$Table) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    tab = xtabs(value ~ is_exposed + disease, data = x) %>%
      as.list() %>%
      setNames(c("d", "c", "b", "a")) %>%
      data.frame()
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  mutate(Risk_d1 = a/(a+b),
         Risk_d0 = c/(c+d),
         Risk_diff = Risk_d1-Risk_d0,
         Odds_ratio = (a*d)/(b*c))

#    d   c  b  a   Risk_d1   Risk_d0  Risk_diff Odds_ratio
# 1 80 100 20  4 0.1666667 0.5555556 -0.3888889       0.16
# 2 30  40 15 10 0.4000000 0.5714286 -0.1714286       0.50
```

Notes:

`xtabs` creates a cross tabulation of `is_exposed` against `disease` and associates `value` to each corresponding cell:

```
df %>%
  split(df$Table) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    tab = xtabs(value ~ is_exposed + disease, data = x)
  })

# $`1`
#           disease
# is_exposed   0   1
#          0  80  20
#          1 100   4
# 
# $`2`
#           disease
# is_exposed  0  1
#          0 30 15
#          1 40 10
```

In order to refer to each cell by `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, I flattened each of these tables with `as.list` and use `setNames` so assign appropriate labels. `lapply` returns a list, so `do.call(rbind, .)` combines the two "rows" and make it into a single dataframe:

```
df %>%
  split(df$Table) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    tab = xtabs(value ~ is_exposed + disease, data = x) %>%
      as.list() %>%
      setNames(c("d", "c", "b", "a")) %>%
      data.frame()
  })

# $`1`
# d   c  b a
# 1 80 100 20 4
# 
# $`2`
# d  c  b  a
# 1 30 40 15 10
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the `xtabs` function?

Comment: @Alex Updated my answer for more explanation. Does the output dataframe look like what you wanted?

Comment: The first output you had was exactly what I was looking for. I was just surprised at how much work was needed to make this happen. I would not have thought that a function with `lapply` was needed, but it makes sense.

Comment: @Alex I agree. I'm sure there is a better way. However, this is generalizable to as many Tables as you want. So maybe not too much work if you have a lot of Tables?